# WebBrowser tries to download local PDF, rather than display it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF C# application and, in one of my windows, I'm having a WebBrowser display a PDF file, which is local. However, when I navigate to this area it tries to download, rather than display. Is there a setting I'm missing, or have I done this wrong?

HelpView.xaml:

`<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding pdfBrowser}"></ContentPresenter>`

HelpViewModel.cs:

```
public WebBrowser pdfBrowser;
...
public HelpViewModel() : base("Help")
{
    pdfBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    pdfBrowser.Navigate("Path/To/PDF/File.pdf");
}
```

Comment: try to change your ContentPresenter to WebBrowser with x:name="pdfBrowser" then in code behind execute pdfWebViewer.Navigate(fullPathToPDF);

Comment: This produces the same issue

Comment: If I click to Open the file, it opens in an Internet Explorer window

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities here.

First thing to consider is you should have a url rather than just a file path. In other words it should start file://

Here's some working code:

```
     private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string unencodedurl = "file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/Welcome.pdf";
        string encodedurl = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(unencodedurl);
        wb.Navigate(encodedurl);
     }
```

Note that this is run once the window is rendered rather than just newing up a control.  I html encode the string.

BTW

You shouldn't have a UI control in a viewmodel.

Comment: This still attempts to download rather than display

Comment: That code above displays the pdf file off my c drive.

Comment: Just want to check, how are you defining / finding `wb`?

Comment: It's a control in my view. Contentrendered means it's definitely been rendered. I also have acrobat reader installed - I didn't choose the pdf randomly. Putting the string as the source property ( and not navigating ) also works <WebBrowser Name="wb" Source="file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/Welcome.pdf"/>